# OPEN3D: How to convert CVPixelBuffer to o3d.geometry.Image

Tags: ios, swift, open3d

I'd like to use the `o3d.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image` function to convert a depth image into point cloud.
Open3D docs say the following: `An Open3D Image can be directly converted to/from a numpy array.`

I have a `CVPixelBuffer` coming from camera.
How to create an `o3d.geometry.Image` from pixel array without saving it to disk first?

here's my code:

```
guard let cameraCalibrationData = frame.cameraCalibrationData else { return }

let frameIntrinsics = cameraCalibrationData.intrinsicMatrix
let referenceDimensions = cameraCalibrationData.intrinsicMatrixReferenceDimensions

let width = Float(referenceDimensions.width)
let height = Float(referenceDimensions.height)
let fx = frameIntrinsics.columns.0[0]
let fy = frameIntrinsics.columns.0[1]
let cx = frameIntrinsics.columns.2[0]
let cy = frameIntrinsics.columns.2[1]

let intrinsics = self.o3d.camera.PinholeCameraIntrinsic()
intrinsics.set_intrinsics(width, height, fx, fy, cx, cy)

//QUESTION HERE:
//how to convert CVPixelBuffer depth to o3d geometry IMAGE ?
let depth : CVPixelBuffer = frame.depthDataMap
let depthImage = self.o3d.geometry.Image()

let cloud = self.o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_depth_image(depthImage, intrinsics)

print(cloud)
```